# jQuery $(document).on() anchor list selection

Tags: jquery, anchor

I'm building a webshop for a project. I'm using a Ajax request to change number of products shown per page. I can't use the .click() method because the element (anchor list) is created dynamically. But if I use .on() method like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".pageNumControl", function(){
    var pageNum=$(".pageNumControl").html();

    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"print.php",
    data: { pageNum:pageNum }
    }).done(function (data){
        $('#content').html(data);
        return false;
    });
});
```

where .pageNumControl is anchor list's class I cannot select the anchor that was clicked. I tried using a:active but to no avail. I'm wondering what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Please provide the related html codes. You can get through console.

Comment: Looks good to me, HTML code would help here.

Comment: `var pageNum=$(this).html();`, but why would you send the HTML to the server ?

Comment: @adeneo's comment should be correct, @adeneo I suggest you to put it as an answer, besides improving suggest not to use or send `$.html()` to the request (but I know that without the `html` is difficult to improve)

Comment: `$(this).text()` even better

Comment: $(this).html() worked, i'm sending html because it's only a number of the page. I can't seem to be able to select an answer as correct?

Comment: OP, there's no answers to select, the good one is a comment. Anyone can answer, (even you or myself) with @adeneo 's comment, but he is the one who should do it... all credits are to him to be the first one to provide the correct answer.

Comment: @gmo - Thanks for pinging me, you go ahead and answer, and just mention my comment in the answer, that's fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **[@adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)** said in his comment <sup>*(all credits goes to him)*</sup>, you must use `$(this)` **to access the element that has been clicked**, and so to get their content and work with.

More info about the *this keyword* can be [founded here](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/).

So, if we modify the original code, form:

```
var pageNum=$(".pageNumControl").html();
```

should be end up in something like:

```
var pageNum=$(this).html();
```

Now, being farsighted and since our code can change over time, it is good to consider the type of content you want to obtain from this selector.

`$(this).html()` returns to us all the html code in the selector, including formatting tags (if any)
In this case (and without knowing the actual code from OP example) maybe will be enough to obtain the text contained in the selector like:

```
var pageNum=$(this).text();
```

*Or maybe not... but it's good to know and take notice.*